# Error while Compressing the Mail DB: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: mail.app, performance, sqlite

I am trying to compress the Mail database by running the sqlite3 `vacuum` command. But I get the following error:

`SQL Error: file is encrypted or is not a database`

I was running Mac OS 10.6 and I upgraded to 10.7. Now, it's running 10.7.4. I found that the Mail data folder is placed under the folder `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData`
instead of `~/Library/Mail/MailData` on my machine.

So I use the following command:

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope\ Index vacuum`

Answer (score 1):

You should just move that file to trash and re-start Mail.

There is a 'PRAGMA integrity_check' option, but why risk a bad index, the file will be rebuilt when Mail senses it's missing.

Comment: Thanks bmike. My question is actually a few month old but what you told is actually what I did at the end.